# HTML dependencies with rmarkdown render

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, flexdashboard

I have a single .Rmd that is being rendered many times with different data being displayed each time in the r chunks.  I want to reuse the same html dependency directory using the lib_dir pandoc option.  This works fine, but the dependencies are recreated each time render is called causing a lot of extra waiting time.  Is there a way to force render to not recreate the dependencies (plotly, bootstrap, htmlwidgets, etc.)?

Comment: I don't have enough time to help you but can give you a tip on how you may help us help you: the dependencies are written out by the function `htmltools::copyDependencyToDir`: https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/blob/a9e969f17d949059f19a91851ee1380e935e3081/R/html_dependency.R#L266 You can check how/where this function is called in rmarkdown: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown then provide a patch (pull request) to allow skipping rewriting dependency files. Thanks! (Or you can just file an issue on Github and wait for us to implement it, which may take months...)